# How to observe input element changes in ng-content

Tags: angular

How to call parent component's function when child component observed input changes?

The below is HTML structure.

```
# app.comopnent.html
<form>
  <textbox>
    <input type="text">
  </textbox>
</form>

# textbox.component.html
<div class="textbox-wrapper">
  <ng-content>
</div>
```

Restrictions are like following.

- TextboxComponent has `ng-content` and need to project `input` element to it.
- Emit an event in TextboxComponent when `input` element is inputted something.
- Don't wanna make `input` element to have more attributes, e.g. `<input type="text" (input)="event()">`.

I was writing code, but cannot find a solution...

```
# input.directive.ts
@Directive({ selector: 'input', ... })
export class InputDirective {
  ngOnChanges(): void {
    // ngOnChanges() can observe only properties defined from @Input Decorator...
  }
}

# textbox.component.ts
@Component({ selector: 'textbox', ... })
export class TextboxComponent {
  @ContentChildren(InputDirective) inputs: QueryList<InputDirective>;
  ngAfterContentInit(): void {
    this.inputs.changes.subscribe((): void => {
      // QueryList has a changes property, it can observe changes when the component add/remove.
      // But cannot observe input changes...
    });
  }
}
```

Comment: Why don't you want to use an output binding, like <input type="text" (input)="event()">?  How can you be sure that other devs (or even you) only add input elements to the TextboxComponent's markup?

Comment: Because I should append an output binding to `input` element and it's verbose if I wanna use it. But I can use `host: { (input): 'event()' }` property in InputDirective instead.
The biggest problem is that TextboxComponent using `ng-content` can detect when InputDirective were inputted anything.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The `input` event is bubbling and can be listened on the parent component

```
<div class="textbox-wrapper" (input)="inputChanged($event)">
  <ng-content></ng-content>
</div>
```

[**Plunker example**](https://plnkr.co/edit/ZZtrPt?p=preview)

Comment: Oh! I didn't know it... I could get behavior expected to!! Thank you!!

Answer (score 6):

In `ngAfterViewInit()`, find the element(s) of interest, then imperatively add event listener(s).  The code below assumes only one input:

```ts
@Component({
    selector: 'textbox',
    template: `<h3>textbox value: {{inputValue}}</h3>
      <div class="textbox-wrapper">
        <ng-content></ng-content>
      </div>`,
})
export class TextboxComp {
  inputValue:string;
  removeListenerFunc: Function;
  constructor(private _elRef:ElementRef, private _renderer:Renderer) {}
  ngAfterContentInit() {
    let inputElement = this._elRef.nativeElement.querySelector('input');
    this.removeListenerFunc = this._renderer.listen(
      inputElement, 'input', 
      event => this.inputValue = event.target.value)
  }
  ngOnDestroy() {
    this.removeListenerFunc();
  }
}
```

<kbd>[Plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/VP1wUe?p=preview)</kbd>

This answer is essentially an imperative approach, in contrast to Günter's declarative approach.  This approach may be easier to extend if you have multiple inputs.

---

There doesn't seem to be a way to use `@ContentChild()` (or `@ContentChildren()`) to find DOM elements in the user-supplied template (i.e, the ng-content content)... something like `@ContentChild(input)` doesn't seem to exist.  Hence the reason I use `querySelector()`.

In this blog post, http://angularjs.blogspot.co.at/2016/04/5-rookie-mistakes-to-avoid-with-angular.html, Kara suggests defining a Directive (say InputItem) with an `input` selector and then using `@ContentChildren(InputItem) inputs: QueryList<InputItem>;`.  Then we don't need to use `querySelector()`. 
However, I don't particularly like this approach because the user of the TextboxComponent has to somehow know to also include InputItem in the `directives` array (I guess some component documentation could solve the problem, but I'm still not a fan).  Here's a [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/tmg8JihmiXpexBG4ZbeH?p=preview) for this approach.

Answer (score 1):

You could use the following scenario, wich has hostbinding property on input directive

*input.directive.ts*

```
import {Directive, HostBinding} from 'angular2/core';
import {Observer} from 'rxjs/Observer';
import {Observable} from 'rxjs/Observable';

@Directive({
  selector: 'input',
  host: {'(input)': 'onInput($event)'}
})
export class InputDirective {
  inputChange$: Observable<string>;
  private _observer: Observer<any>;
  constructor() {
    this.inputChange$ = new Observable(observer => this._observer = observer);
  }
  onInput(event) {
    this._observer.next(event.target.value);
  }
}
```

And then your TextBoxComponent will subscribe on Observable object that defined above in InputDirective class.

*textbox.component.ts*

```
import {Component, ContentChildren,QueryList} from 'angular2/core';
import {InputDirective} from './input.directive';
@Component({
  selector: 'textbox',
  template: `
    <div class="textbox-wrapper">
      <ng-content></ng-content>
      <div *ngFor="#change of changes">
        {{change}}
      </div>
    </div>
  `
})
export class TextboxComponent {
  private changes: Array<string> = [];
  @ContentChildren(InputDirective) inputs: QueryList<InputDirective>;

  onChange(value, index) {
    this.changes.push(`input${index}: ${value}`);
  }

  ngAfterContentInit(): void {
    this.inputs.toArray().forEach((input, index) => {
      input.inputChange$.subscribe(value => this.onChange(value, index + 1));
    });
  }
}
```

Here's plunker [sample](https://plnkr.co/edit/TpJ6Zu8QovWINqx04KUY?p=preview)

Answer (score 1):

You can use Angular CDK observers https://material.angular.io/cdk/observers/api

import this module in your module

```
import { ObserversModule } from '@angular/cdk/observers';
```

then use in `ng-content's` parent element

```
<div class="projected-content-wrapper (cdkObserveContent)="contentChanged()">
 <ng-content></ng-content>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could add an ngControl on your input element.

```
<form>
  <textbox>
    <input ngControl="test"/>
  </textbox>
</form>
```

This way you would be able to use NgControl within ContentChild. It tiges access to the valueChanges property you can register on to be notified of updates.

```
@Component({ selector: 'textbox', ... })
export class TextboxComponent {
  @ContentChild(NgControl) input: NgControl;
  ngAfterContentInit(): void {
    this.input.control.valueChanges.subscribe((): void => {
      (...)
    });
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you. I cannot get expected to because of using `ngAfterContentInit`. I got emitted event when using `ngAfterViewChecked`, but it executed many times...